# Limitations of Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach

I have this code in Excel VBA that checks the dates of some records and checks to see if it is within the date range that we are looking for.  This code seemed to be working well last week, but suddenly it is now skipping records.  What I found, is if I were to step through the coding, it picks up all records, but if I let it run, it seems to skip over records.  Can anyone help explain the cause.  I'm fairly new to VBA and I'm sure some will cringe at the coding, but its what I knew and had working under the deadlines I had.  Any assistance in explaining what is happening and possible solution to avoid this is welcomed.

```
    MaxDate = ReportDate + 2
    MinDate = ReportDate - 6
    
    Set DatesEntryRange = Range("A2:A" & LastRowArray(2))
    
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( "A", "R", "S"), 
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:= "Company Name"
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=Array( "Closed", "Completed", 
"Draft", "Implementation In Progress", "Pending", "Planning In Progress", "Request For Authorization", "Request For Change", "Scheduled", "Scheduled For Approval", "Scheduled For Review"), Operator:= xlFilterValues
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:= "=Emergency", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Expedited"
    
    For Each DateEntry In DatesEntryRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If ErrorOccurance <> True Then
            DateEntry.Select
        Else
            ErrorOccurance = False
            GoTo NextCriteria1
        End If

    Select Case Cells(DateEntry.Row, "A").Value
    Case "R"
        If Cells(DateEntry.Row, "B").Value >= MinDate And Cells(DateEntry.Row, "B").Value < MaxDate Then
            Cells(DateEntry.Row, "M").Interior.Color = RGB(RED, GREEN, BLUE)
        ElseIf Cells(DateEntry.Row, "C").Value >= MinDate And Cells(DateEntry.Row, "C").Value < MaxDate Then
            Cells(DateEntry.Row, "M").Interior.Color = RGB(RED, GREEN, BLUE)
        ElseIf Cells(DateEntry.Row, "B").Value < MinDate And Cells(DateEntry.Row, "C").Value >= MaxDate Then
            Cells(DateEntry.Row, "M").Interior.Color = RGB(RED, GREEN, BLUE)
        Else
        End If
    Case "S"
        If Cells(DateEntry.Row, "D").Value >= MinDate And Cells(DateEntry.Row, "D").Value < MaxDate Then
            Cells(DateEntry.Row, "M").Interior.Color = RGB(RED, GREEN, BLUE)
        ElseIf Cells(DateEntry.Row, "E").Value >= MinDate And Cells(DateEntry.Row, "E").Value < MaxDate Then
            Cells(DateEntry.Row, "M").Interior.Color = RGB(RED, GREEN, BLUE)
        ElseIf Cells(DateEntry.Row, "D").Value < MinDate And Cells(DateEntry.Row, "E").Value >= MaxDate Then
            Cells(DateEntry.Row, "M").Interior.Color = RGB(RED, GREEN, BLUE)
        Else
        End If
    Case "A"
        If Cells(DateEntry.Row, "F").Value >= MinDate And Cells(DateEntry.Row, "F").Value < MaxDate Then
            Cells(DateEntry.Row, "M").Interior.Color = RGB(RED, GREEN, BLUE)
        ElseIf Cells(DateEntry.Row, "G").Value >= MinDate And Cells(DateEntry.Row, "G").Value < MaxDate Then
            Cells(DateEntry.Row, "M").Interior.Color = RGB(RED, GREEN, BLUE)
        ElseIf Cells(DateEntry.Row, "F").Value < MinDate And Cells(DateEntry.Row, "G").Value >= MaxDate Then
            Cells(DateEntry.Row, "M").Interior.Color = RGB(RED, GREEN, BLUE)
        Else
        End If
    Case Else
        GoTo NextCriteria1
   End Select
Next
```

The reportdate is a date variable and columns B thru H are all dates.  LastRowArray is an integer array that holds the last cell row for each report that I'm generating.  Hoping someone here can help explain why it would skip.

EDIT: Made some of the change as per the comments.  Issue still remains where Excel cannot find data or skips it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: First step, get rid of those `GoTo`s. That creates spaghetti code.

Comment: Then don't rely on `ActiveCell` in for example `Select Case ActiveCell.Value`. The use of `ActiveCell` seems quite out of place in your loop here.

Comment: By getting rid of ActiveCell in the select statement, will it help in the skipping of data?

Comment: I have updated the code by removing the activecell parts.  The issue still remains.  It seems to only occur if I'm running more than one report.  To clarify, the macro runs through report A, saves it, moves to B, saves it and then on to C.  As an example, B should show 25 items, but it only shows 15.  If I step through it, it finds all 25, where as letting it run does not for some reason.

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question with your revised code.

Comment: @BigBen, I have updated it as suggested.  Seen some of the suggested edits of the code and I understand some of them and could do that, but at the moment I'd like to figure out why data is being skipped?  Any suggestions?  As per my previous comment, if I run each report individual, there is no issue.  Just when I try and group them together to run.

Comment: Generous use of `Debug.Print` to trace code execution might be helpful.